# $\Sigma \vDash \exists x a(x)$ if and only if $\Sigma \vDash (\neg \forall x( \neg a(x))).$

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, first-order-logic

This is the proof I was provided in one direction.

[image]

I am confused as to why there is a necessity to introduce variables $s, d$. How does one make the leap there $\exists d$. Any proof clarification would be really appreciated!

Comment: In order for $\exists x\alpha(x)$ to hold in your model $\mathcal M$, there must really exist a thing $d$ in that model that does have property $\alpha$, i.e., $\alpha(d)$ holds for that $d$

Comment: $s$ is **not** a *variable* : it is a variable assignment function. Please, review the relevant clause of the definition of $\vDash$.

Comment: $d$ is **not** a *variable*. Is the name of an "object" (an element of the *domain* $M$ of $\mathcal M$) that satisfies the formula $\alpha(x)$.